# How do journals remain objective, if they are for-profit entities (with for-profit interest)?

Tags: publications

How do journals remain objective, if they are for-profit entities (with for-profit interest)?

Occasionally, something being for-profit is seen to influence the goals and interests. This creates some believability problems like:

- If the publication has to produce money, then why do we trust its
  objective?
- If the publication produces money, then why do we need to measure its
  utility, if it already produces money (i.e. it has a capitalistic
  need)?

In fact, if we'd trust the economic measure, then just like in other things, "whether someone buys it" is a measure for quality. However, it's certainly possible to sell *what people want to read*, which is not necessarily correlated with information quality (compare to e.g. tabloid magazines).

Technically it would also be possible that "influencers" would be bought so that people who write and selected people who publish would both win, just like in some other industry where those who profit can also be those who control.

Comment: It is the editorial board that decides what papers are accepted. In my field, math, editors and referees do their work for free.

Comment: I am not finding this post very clear - "compensated" by who, for what purpose? What does "compensated" mean? Are you contrasting journals with different publication models, for-profit versus non-profit publishing, what?

Comment: @BryanKrause Well, compare to newspapers. They sometimes sell, because they have things that *people want to read about*, which is not necessarily the same as *being most objective, ...*. So certainly it's then possible to publish things that have high sales, but which are not high-quality in information.

Comment: I mean that to strengthen quality, one may then have to reduce the incentive for selling what people want to read, like above.

Comment: The market for a journal is completely different from the market for a general-circulation newspaper. And, these days, most publishing is happening "open access", where the authors pay, not the readers. I think it's going to be difficult for you to write a question about these things if you're not familiar with these concepts in academic publishing. It might help to start by mentioning your assumptions and understanding. I fear, though, that the question will end up far too broad and unfocused.

Comment: @BryanKrause Is it? If publications are used as a measure to teach in *public* universities?

Comment: Huh? The typical audience for journal articles are researchers in the field. Subscriptions to journals are typically purchased by university libraries so academics at that institution can read them; that's the audience. I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: There is enough grift to go around in not-for-profit endeavors as well.  Even for an open access journal, money -- of course -- is part of the picture, even for open access.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give it a try.

What you described might be something a disreputable publisher might try, and maybe has, but a reputable publisher can't do that and maintain their reputation.

In fact the same situation applies to many other businesses. As a business, it is responsible to its shareholders to make a profit, and it is responsible to its customers to maintain trust in its quality. It is a balance, but without the trust of the customers there is nothing that can be done to satisfy shareholders in the long term.

If you make widgets for sale and the customers think you make junk, then you don't sell many widgets, so the shareholders get after you to make better widgets.

The practices you describe couldn't be carried out in secret for very long. Word would get out. Academics wouldn't trust the journal to provide good scholarship, science or whatever. So, publishing there wouldn't enhance your reputation and sales of the journal would soon fall. Librarians, who buy a lot of academic stuff, are smart enough to know these things.

So, while money is *a* driver, it isn't the only driver. Reputation matters. Think about what has happened to the profitability of the social media site formerly known as Twitter as a current example.

Comment: This is a good answer, don't know why the question is downvoted, because this is what is asked for.